# Spring Boot app with Swagger Works on Localhost but Cannot find swagger-ui.jar when Deployed to ec2

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, swagger-ui

spring boot app with swagger works on localhost but cannot find swagger-ui.jar when deployed to ec2.

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

> Wed Aug 23 20:37:15 UTC 2017 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Unable to open root Jar file
>   'war:file:/home/ubuntu/myapp.jar*/BOOT-INF/lib/springfox-swagger-ui-2.7.0.jar'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the aws ec2 has the open java jdk installed, and for some reason it really doesnt like alot of coding, after change java to oracle, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `swagger-ui.html`should be mapped correctly

For example:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
```

You can find more details in closed [`springfox`](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1752) issue